# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total') in React code

Tags: reactjs, api, redux-toolkit

Using the coinranking API to get coin info and the code keeps on throwing this error, I have no idea what's wrong, It was running previously locally but threw that error when I attempted to host it. Now its throwing the error locally as well, I think it has something to do with the syntax in the global stats initialization but I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import millify from 'millify';
import { Typography, Row, Col, Statistic } from 'antd';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import { useGetCryptosQuery } from '../services/cryptoApi';
import Cryptocurrencies from './Cryptocurrencies';
import News from './News';
import Loader from './Loader';

const { Title } = Typography;

const Homepage = () => {
  const { data, isFetching } = useGetCryptosQuery(10);
  const globalStats = data?.data?.stats;

  if (isFetching) return <Loader />;

  return (
    <>
      <Title level={2} className="heading">Global Crypto Stats</Title>
      <Row gutter={[32, 32]}>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats.total} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Exchanges" value={millify(globalStats.totalExchanges)} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Market Cap:" value={`$${millify(globalStats.totalMarketCap)}`} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total 24h Volume" value={`$${millify(globalStats.total24hVolume)}`} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats.total} /></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Markets" value={millify(globalStats.totalMarkets)} /></Col>
      </Row>
      <div className="home-heading-container">
        <Title level={2} className="home-title">Top 10 Cryptos In The World</Title>
        <Title level={3} className="show-more"><Link to="/cryptocurrencies">Show more</Link></Title>
      </div>
      <Cryptocurrencies simplified />
      <div className="home-heading-container">
        <Title level={2} className="home-title">Latest Crypto News</Title>
        <Title level={3}><Link to="/news">Show more</Link></Title>
      </div>
      <News simplified />
    </>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

Comment: By the sounds of things, the `useGetCryptosQuery` hook isn't returning any `data`, or the data that is being returned isn't returning any `stats`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `if (isFetching && globalStats) return <Loader />`

Initially when rendering, globalStats can happen to be undefined, this way you keep code from breaking when it tries to access property of undefined

Comment: Hi, did you mean this `if (isFetching || !globalStats) return <Loader />`? I think your logic is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there is a scenario where `isFetching` is `false` AND `globalStats` is `undefined`.

When trying to access properties of `globalStats` while `globalStats` is `undefined`, that error will be thrown.

There are 2 ways to solve this

**Solution 1:**

Add a guard statement to `return null` or your loading banner (depends what you want your fallback to be):

```
if (!globalStats) return null; // or return your LoadingBanner
```

**Solution 2:**

Everywhere you have `globalStats.` defined you can optional chain your properties like `globalStats?.myProperty` and then you can do an empty string as a fallback like this: `globalStats?.myProperty || ""`.

In you scenario you'll need to change your stats content to this:

```
<Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats?.total || ""} />
<Statistic title="Total Exchanges" value={millify(globalStats?.totalExchanges || "")} />
<Statistic title="Total Market Cap:" value={`$${millify(globalStats?.totalMarketCap || "")}`} />
<Statistic title="Total 24h Volume" value={`$${millify(globalStats?.total24hVolume || "")}`} />
<Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats?.total || ""} />
<Statistic title="Total Markets" value={millify(globalStats?.totalMarkets "")} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!globalStats || isFetching) return 'Loading...'
else return (
    <>
      <Title level={2} className="heading">Global Crypto Stats</Title>
      <Row>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Cryptocurrencies" value={globalStats.total}/></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Exchanges" value={millify(globalStats.totalExchanges)}/></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Market Cap" value={`$${millify(globalStats.totalMarketCap)}`}/></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total 24h Volume" value={`$${millify(globalStats.total24hVolume)}`}/></Col>
        <Col span={12}><Statistic title="Total Markets" value={millify(globalStats.totalMarkets)}/></Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  )
```